# Approximate the two-body density matrix in terms of product of one-body density matrices

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, approximations, many-body, second-quantization

Given a set of boson operators $\hat a_\alpha$, i.e. satisfying
$[\hat a_\alpha,\hat a^\dagger_\beta]=\delta_{\alpha,\beta}$, the one-body density matrix
$\rho^{(1)}_{\alpha\beta}$ is defined via the following trace operation on the many-body density matrix $\hat \rho$

$\rho^{(1)}_{\alpha\beta}={\rm Tr}(\hat \rho \hat a^\dagger_\beta \hat a_\alpha)$

and the two-body density matrix is defined as:

$\rho^{(2)}_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}={\rm Tr}(\hat \rho \hat a^\dagger_\delta \hat a^\dagger_\gamma \hat a_\beta \hat a_\alpha)$

Now my question is about how to approximate the two-body density matrix in terms of products of one-body density matrices.

The following approximation is found in textbooks (only black terms) [e.g. Vasko and Raichev, Quantum Kinetic Theory and Applications, Springer 2005, Eq 10 pag 192]:

$$
\rho^{(2)}_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}\approx\rho^{(1)}_{\alpha\gamma}\rho^{(1)}_{\beta\delta} + \rho^{(1)}_{\alpha\delta}\rho^{(1)}_{\beta\gamma}+\color{red}{{\rm Tr}(\hat \rho \hat a^\dagger_\delta \hat a^\dagger_\gamma)}\color{red}{{\rm Tr}(\hat \rho \hat a_\beta \hat a_\alpha)}
$$

In reading research articles (Eq. 10.1 https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0505025 ), I've found that something like the red term is reported, and then discarded saying that it vanishes by assumption.
What is the physical meaning of the red term? Are there conditions in which it could be relevant and written approximatively in terms of one-body matrices?

Comment: Please add the relevant references.

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of quasi free states? Is it assumed that your state $\rho$ has a definite particle number?

Comment: My question is general, unrelated to the specific example discusses in the article cited. In general, is it possible to refine the mean field approximation for bosons' 2-body density matrices? The article and book cited deal with only the diagonal elements of the density matrices (well defined particle numbers), but if one wants to consider off-diagonal elements (coherences), should the term in red be considered? If yes, can It be expressed in terms of one-body matrices?

Comment: The terms in red are zero for particle number conserving systems...What do you mean with off-diagonal elements? E.g. $\rho^{(1)}_{\alpha\gamma}$ is also a off-diagonal element.

Comment: In the specific case of phonons, the number of quasiparticles is not a conserved quantity. Is there any book discussing how to approximate the red term as a product of one-body density matrices?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. However, these terms appear in the so-called generalized one-body reduced density matrix (also called generalized one-particle density matrix).